# How to move table caption to a new page

Tags: tables, landscape

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
{\scriptsize
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{rccccccc}
  \hline
1 & 2&  3 &   4& 5  & 6  &a & b \\ 
\end{tabular}}
}
\end{center}
\caption{this is a caption}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

I have a table in landscape mode that is so large that its caption gets cut off on the page even if I use `\resizebox`. I want to move the caption to the next page. I tried simply adding `\newpage` before `\caption` but that did not work.

Comment: resizing tables should only be done as a last resort, also in landscape you want to use `\linewidth` not `\textwidth` as the latter refers to the original portrait text width.  a `table` is an umbreakable box if you want the caption on another page then you will need to take it out of the `table`. Also use `\centering` not `center` as the latter uses up space that might make the caption fit.

Comment: The problem is not the caption but the obstinacy  to put a meeting table in the broom closet. Do you want to punish readers with a whole page of a shortened version (`\resizebox`) of an already too small font (`\scriptsize`)? Moreover, forcing them to have to turn the page or twist the neck but while lookong for a caption that is in another page? Consider the redesign of the table, or better, consider show that information in another format.

Comment: Since there is an automatic \clearpage at the beginning and end of landcape, you might as well use [p] tables, one for each page.